# Is there a way to import constants into a Gruntfile.js file?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have no prior experience with grunt, but I've been tasked with seeing if there's a way to prune the gruntfile.js files down a little (they are massive). As I pick through them, I see that a good 30%  of them is defining the same constants in every file (these are paths to things specific to our environments).

My first thought was that that big chunk could be moved into a common file and each gruntfile.js could import all those paths from a single file, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it online. Does anyone out there have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gruntfile.js is a regular JavaScript file; you can import variables from another file into it the same way you would in any other JS file. From the MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export:

> In the module, we could use the following code:

```
// module "my-module.js"
function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
const foo = Math.PI + Math.SQRT2;
var graph = {
    options:{
        color:'white',
        thickness:'2px'
    },
    draw: function(){
        console.log('From graph draw function');
    }
}
export { cube, foo, graph };
```

> This way, in another script, we could have:

```
import { cube, foo, graph } from 'my-module';
graph.options = {
    color:'blue',
    thickness:'3px'
}; 
graph.draw();
console.log(cube(3)); // 27
console.log(foo);    // 4.555806215962888
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define all the constants in a separate module or JSON file and `require()` it later.

`constants.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    constant1: 'abc',
    constant2: 1234
}
```

Then in your `gruntfile.js`:

```
const constants = require('./constants')
constants.constant1 === 'abc' // true
```

You can also define the constants in a JSON file

`constants.json`

```
{
    "constant1": "abc",
    "constant2": 1234,
}
```

And `require()` it the same way, `const constants = require('./constants')`